# How to enable keydown for full document and disable keydown for one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using fancybox for form popup and my client does not want to background should be scroll

Firefox is still allow user to scroll background via arrow keys.

Now I blocked the user to press arrow key till popup for complete document, but it will stop the same keydown in my form also.

is these any option for user to block event for all document except form ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this-

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
  if ($(event.target).is('.theForm'))
      event.stopPropogation();
  else
      // block scrolling  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable keydown for full document:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  var charCode = event.which;
  alert('Handler for .keydown() called - ' + charCode );
});
```

And to disable keydown for one div:

```
$('#target').keydown(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

where `target` is the ID of the specific div.

Comment: No need anymore to check for `event.keyCode`, since it's jQuery event object it will always be just `event.which`. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/). (*To determine which key was pressed, examine the event object that is passed to the handler function. While browsers use differing properties to store this information, jQuery normalizes the .which property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the key code*)